# Cardinality of set of linear maps

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be an $n$ dimensional vector space over the field $\mathbb{F}_p$. I want to compute the cardinality of the set of linear maps $f:V\to V$.

I know that the cardinality of $V$ is $p^n$, I'm not sure if this helps me though. How do I go about finding this?

Comment: Well, a linear map can still be represented by a $n\times n$ matrix, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix a basis $\langle v_1,\ldots,v_n\rangle$ of $V$. Any choice of elements $\langle w_1,\ldots,w_n\rangle$ of elements of $V$ defines uniquely a linear mapping by $v_i \mapsto w_i$, and this covers all of them, hence the number of linear mappings $V \to V$ is given by
$$
|V|^n = (p^n)^n = p^{n^2}.
$$
Alternatively, note that this is the number of $n \times n$ matrices with entries in $\mathbb F_p$.